# ¿Como mostrar visualmente un juego en Android Studio sin usar LibGDX?

Tags: android, android-studio

Me gustaría saber formas de poder mostrar en pantalla un juego de "Snake" que estoy creando.
Visualmente, tengo un ImageView para mostrarlo. Así es cómo se ve por ahora: [image: Así se ve el juego por ahora]

El problema está en que el controlador no consigo actualizarlo, al buscar por internet por soluciones, todas las que he encontrado, me llevan a usar libGDX pero al importarlo siempre me da error (puede ser que desconozca como importarlo correctamente).

El "mapa" en el que guardo la información es una matriz de char:

`private char[][] map`

Comment: Entonces que quieres? Saber importar correctamente libGDX o buscar otra alternativo a parte de esa

Comment: Preferiría encontrar una alternativa, estoy intentando usar un Bitmap para actualizar el ImageView, pero aún no he conseguido avances